# How to Manage ACS Service Identities

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles, acs, acs-serviceidentity

I host a WCF 4.5 service in azure WebRole
and I use Azure ACS Service Identities to manage my wcf users (*active authentication*).
this model is accepted for me because we have a limited number of users

Now I want to know How can I manage (Create/Read/Update/Delete) ACS Service Identities **programmatically** via C# code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [ACS Management Service API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh278947.aspx) which has [`ServiceIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180757.aspx) management.

The management endpoint is located here: 
 **https://NAMESPACE.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/mgmt/service**

You can leverage this ACS Management service to create new `ServiceIdentities`

```cs
string name = "SampleServiceIdentity";
string password = "SampleServiceIdentityPassword";
ServiceIdentity sid = new ServiceIdentity()
{
    Name = name
};

DateTime startDate, endDate;
startDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
endDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

ServiceIdentityKey key = new ServiceIdentityKey()
{
    EndDate = endDate.ToUniversalTime(),
    StartDate = startDate.ToUniversalTime(),
    Type = "Password",
    Usage = "Password",
    Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password),
    DisplayName = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} key for {1}", "Password", name)
};

svc.AddToServiceIdentities(sid);
svc.AddRelatedObject(
    sid,
    "ServiceIdentityKeys",
    key);


svc.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch);
```

This example is from [MSDN - How to: Use ACS Management Service to Configure Service Identies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh135148.aspx).

Comment: The ACS Management Service interaction is actually a series of steps - if you follow the [MSDN article reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh135148.aspx) it should answer your HOW. You need to authenticate with the endpoint and then you can perform CRUD ops with your identities.

Answer (score 1):

A simple how to demo called **Invoking the ACS management service programmatically** is [here](http://www.corradin.net/index.php/2013/01/invoking-the-acs-management-service-programmatically/)